# Can someone using Water Walk attack a creature just below the water's suface?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, attack

Particularly, I want to know if a creature using the Water Walk spell can make a *melee* attack against a creature just under the water's surface.  For that matter, what about a melee attack with reach?

Comment: Do you care about distinctions between using manufactured vs. natural weapons?

Comment: @minnmass Primarily interested in manufactured weapons, but wouldn't mind also knowing for natural weapons.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, but the creature has cover

As explained on [Aquatic Adventures](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9toq?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Aquatic-Adventures), an attacker on land, and by this it means a creature that not at least partially submerged in water, cannot easily attack a creature that is partially or fully submerged ([SRD reference](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/wilderness/terrain/aquatic-terrain/)):

> **Attacks from Land**: Characters swimming, floating, or treading water on the surface, or wading in water at least chest deep, have **improved cover** (+8 bonus to AC, +4 bonus on Reflex saves) from opponents on land. Land-bound opponents who have freedom of movement effects ignore this cover when making melee attacks against targets in the water. A completely submerged creature has total cover against opponents on land unless those opponents have freedom of movement effects. Magical effects are unaffected except for those that require attack rolls (which are treated like any other effects) and fire effects.

And [Water Walk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/water-walk/) doesnt seem to prevent you from attacking, it simply limits your movement to walk, run, charge, etc while on water surfaces.

> The transmuted creatures can tread on any liquid as if it were firm ground. Mud, oil, snow, quicksand, running water, ice, and even lava can be traversed easily, since the subjects’ feet hover an inch or two above the surface. Creatures crossing molten lava still take damage from the heat because they are near it. **The subjects can walk, run, charge, or otherwise move across the surface as if it were normal ground.**

Note that the spell says *you can*, not that *you have to*. This is open to interpretation and table variation, and some GM's may allow a creature under the effects of the spell to get pulled into water or take a swim, while some GM's will treat water as solid ground for that creature's movement. Regardless of the decision, there is no mention of the spell affecting your attacks, and you normally can attack the ground either way (it's simply not very effective).